# Как узнать какой скрипт/программа создает определенную папку на сервере?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, безопасность

В корне сайта периодически появляется папка `temp` с непонятными файлами. Я думаю что это какой-то шелл создает его чтобы заполнить память диска. Я его удаляю, а на следующий день он заново создается и в нем снова непонятные файлы.

Поискал в сети что это может быть за папка. Узнал что многие программы создают его для отчетов и прочих данных. Как я могу уточнить это серверная программа делает это или на сервер залит шелл?

Например файл `example.com/temp/u/d3d3LmZsYXRvdXIuY29tL215YWR2cy9ydS8%3D.tx‌​t` содержит лишь строку

```
dHJlYXN1cmV0b3duLzQ1NDg3NDUyOTQzMjMv
```

И эта папка состоит только из таких файлов.
Сервер у меня Centos6, VPS, панель ISPmanager, включен nginx, memcached, clamav.

Comment: Непонятная папка и файлы - очень обтекаемая формулировка. Уточните, пожалуйста, имена файлов и примеры содержания.

Comment: Например содержимое файла http://example.com/temp/u/d3d3LmZsYXRvdXIuY29tL215YWR2cy9ydS8%3D.txt
dHJlYXN1cmV0b3duLzQ1NDg3NDUyOTQzMjMv

Comment: Имя файла и содержимое это строка в кодировке base64. Имя файла содержит такую ссылку: `www.flatour.com/myadvs/ru/`, а содержимое после расшифровки такое: `treasuretown/4548745294323/`

Comment: И что это значит? Да это сайт на котором эти проблемы...Но вопрос все еще остается в силе....что создает эти файлы

Comment: Похоже, что `treasuretown` это часть этого url: `http://item.rakuten.co.jp/treasuretown/4548745294323/`. Возможно, с вашего сайта продают ссылки. Проверьте файлы сайта [манулом](https://yandex.ru/promo/manul#about)

Comment: Этот rakuten мне знаком...я если не ошибаюсь натыкался на него из скриптов addthis

Comment: Вы правы, память вас не подводит. Связь упоминается [здесь](http://www.addthis.com/press/addthis-appoints-scott-allan-as-chief-marketing-officer#.V8BTfiOhpBc)

Comment: Что посоветуете сделать?Отказаться от addthis? Я не думал что настолько популярный сервис будет внедрять вирусы своим клиентам.И когда впервые наткнулся на этот китайский сайт,решил что просто сервис свои скрипты держит на разных серверах. Потому и ничего не предпринимал против этово

Comment: Я когда-то давно использовал этот сервис, как итог пришлось отказаться по схожей причине. Альтернатив на рынке много. По поводу популярности: к сожалению, она не означает порядочность.

Comment: Хотел проверить манул..не работает..выдает ошибку chmod(): Operation not permitted.. Попробовал сменить владельца...сделал 777 рекурсивно но результат тотже

Comment: Не на боевом сервере это надо делать, а на локальной копии. А вообще это говорит что у пользователя, под которым вы зашли, недостаточно прав на это

Comment: сменил название папки - манул заработал...Каким аналогом addthis вы пользуетесь? Я просто не хочу заного изобретать велосипед

Comment: Если это делать на локальной копии то придется ждать несколько часов, а может и день..на сайте аплоадов много..А пропустить копирование этой папки думаю будет не верным решением...ведь вирус может быть именно в нем

Comment: Yandex Share или Pluso

Answer (score 6):

Можно попробовать запустить команду `lsof`, которая отображает какая программа в данный момент открыла файл. Работает так:

```
$ lsof /path/to/file
```

Можно запустить с периодом в 1 секунду:

```
$ lsof -r1 /path/to/file
```

Ну и логгировать это всё в файл. Если держать при этом открытой ssh сессию не хочется, то можно использовать какой-нибудь gnu screen или подобную программу.

Если программа отрабатывает слишком быстро и по этим логам её поймать не получится, то можно сделать ну совсем костыльно запускать как можно чаще

```
$ while true; do lsof /paht/to/file; done;
```

Comment: попробовал lsof... никаких результатов

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev lsof показывает только в текущий момент, надо запустить его на какое-то время. На сутки, например. Потом анализируйте логи через grep, например

Comment: Извиняюсь...неправильно вставлял код, в ssh опыта мало...подправил,сечас выводит Permission denied

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev этот код можно безопасно запускать из под администратора. su или sudo su попробуйте, я в centos не очень разбираюсь

Comment: выдает does not exist

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev, если задача в самом деле актуальна, я бы написал некий "watchdog" на основе [man inotyfy](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify), который будучи запущенным в фоне, мониторит оглавление и при получении событий `IN_CREATE `и может быть `IN_MOVED_TO` вызывает `lsof` (или imho более легкий `fuser`)

Answer (score 2):

Вам может помочь пакет **auditd**.
Пример:

```
# auditctl -w /temp
# mkdir /temp
# mkdir /temp/u
# ausearch -f /temp
----
time->Mon Aug 29 16:32:43 2016
type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(1472473963.517:46): auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="updated_rules" path="/temp" key=(null) list=4 res=1
----
time->Mon Aug 29 16:32:43 2016
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1472473963.489:47): proctitle=6D6B646972002F74656D70
type=PATH msg=audit(1472473963.489:47): item=1 name="/temp" inode=10691 dev=08:03 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE
type=PATH msg=audit(1472473963.489:47): item=0 name="/" inode=2 dev=08:03 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(1472473963.489:47):  cwd=2F686F6D652F73657267696F2F456CC59D75746F6A
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1472473963.489:47): arch=40000003 syscall=39 success=yes exit=0 a0=bf82f7a3 a1=1ff a2=bf82f7a3 a3=bf82ee64 items=2 ppid=22390 pid=24813 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts8 ses=4294967295 comm="mkdir" exe="/bin/mkdir" key=(null)
----
time->Mon Aug 29 16:34:21 2016
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1472474061.417:71): proctitle=6D6B646972002F74656D702F75
type=PATH msg=audit(1472474061.417:71): item=1 name="/temp/u" inode=10693 dev=08:03 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE
type=PATH msg=audit(1472474061.417:71): item=0 name="/temp/" inode=10691 dev=08:03 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(1472474061.417:71):  cwd=2F686F6D652F73657267696F2F456CC59D75746F6A
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1472474061.417:71): arch=40000003 syscall=39 success=yes exit=0 a0=bfe2c7a1 a1=1ff a2=bfe2c7a1 a3=bfe2a9a4 items=2 ppid=22390 pid=24846 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts8 ses=4294967295 comm="mkdir" exe="/bin/mkdir" key=(null)
```