# Как найти шелл залитый на сервер?

Tags: php, linux, безопасность, shell, scanner

Нашёл в сети кучу гайдов... но не помогает. Все проверки/поиски пользуясь grep и find показывают что шелла нет. Но всеравно каждый день происходят изменения в индексовом файле... добавляются такие строки:

```
 ${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["n\x6b\x67l\x61\x6f\x77c"]="k\x77_\x61\x72\x72";${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4cS"}["a\x67\x6eei\x73\x73p\x63\x68\x66"]="\x6b\x77\x73";${"GL\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x6a\x64\x78\x79\x71q\x6e\x77o"]="A\x72\x74i\x63l\x65\x5fca\x74egory";${"\x47LOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x67l\x6cz\x69\x73\x6d\x63\x74\x70\x68"]="c\x6f\x6e\x74e\x6et";${"\x47\x4c\x4fBALS"}["\x65d\x75s\x79e\x77\x6f"]="\x41\x72\x74\x69c\x6ce\x5f\x54\x69\x74l\x65";${"\x47L\x4f\x42A\x4c\x53"}["h\x6a\x68\x78h\x64\x72\x77"]="\x4dat\x65_\x44\x65s\x63\x72i\x70\x74ion";${"GL\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x73\x64a\x6dy\x65u\x65"]="M\x61\x74\x65_\x4b\x65\x79\x77\x6fr\x64";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42ALS"}
```

Как найти этот шелл? Манул и Айболит не помогли.Связался с тех поддержкой vps, проверили через свой платный антивирус но он тоже показал что сервер чист(при этом индексовый файл все еще содержал эти строки) проверял также через clamscan. Тоже результат нулевой. Может есть какието другие способы, о которых я просто не смог разузнать?

Comment: Так может не сервер заражен, а у вас в браузере идет добавление кода на страницу? Или даже не в браузере, а по пути между сайтом и компьютером, например: в роутере?

Comment: Не понял.  Браузер будет добавлять PHP строки в файл на сервере????

Comment: :) Попутал, смутил меня начальный $, мысли двинулись в сторону jQuery.

Comment: Как быстро появляется вредоносный код после его удаления? Если быстро, проверьте список заданий CRON'а, возможно по крону что-то есть.  если в кроне ничего нет, значит шел доступен из вэба, инициализируйте git репозитории во всех Ваших проектах, проверьте списки файлов на подозрительные, закомитьте изменения и мониторьте какие файлы меняются, это позволит в будущем находить левый код одной командой `git status`

Comment: Учитывая содержание этого текста: `${"GLOBALS"}["nkglaowc"]="kw_arr";${"GLOBALS"}["agneisspchf"]="kws";${"GLOBALS"}["jdxyqqnwo"]="Article_category";${"GLOBALS"}["gllzismctph"]="content";${"GLOBALS"}["edusyewo"]="Article_Title";${"GLOBALS"}["hjhxhdrw"]="Mate_Description";${"GLOBALS"}["sdamyeue"]="Mate_Keyword";${"GLOBALS"}` я бы сказал, что это пишет не шелл или вирус а какая то CMS, озабоченная безопасностью своих исходников

Comment: @Mike Это все началось после добавления на страницы сайта виджета addthis...Он вставляет эти строки(я вставил лишь фрагмент, весь код очень громоздкий), а их результатом является папка с захешированными текстовыми файлами...потом он получая эти файлы из этой папки подставляет в тайтлы страниц...В итоге и скорость убивает и SEO

Comment: Значит оторвать руки и не только руки разработчикам этого addthis

Comment: @naym в кронах только мои файлы, но на всякий случай проверил - чистые...а насчет git не использовал..не знаю вообще как это работает..но спасибо,поггуглю,может он чемто поможет

Comment: @Mike к сожалению в сети об этом почти ничего нет..Но этот addthis даже не стесняется упоминать свой китайский сайт rakuten в описании, на который и вставляет ссылки на сайтах своих пользователей

Comment: Значит не использовать этот модуль или пересмотреть его исходники и  убрать все лишнее. а шелла значит нет на машине. не только же шеллы себя шифруют. вот модули шифруются что бы сложнее из них было рекламу вырезать ...

Comment: Я удалил уже все что касается addthis...Но он уже внедрил шелл...два дня как удалил...а папка с хеш файлам и код громоздкий в индекс все еще добавляется

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559809/130